# Retrieving selected text from textarea when span is clicked in IE

Tags: javascript

I want to get the selected text within the text area when 'span' is clicked. When I click button the selection works but not when I click on span.
Maybe because the selection is lost when span is clicked, but it's not happening when button is clicked? 
How to fix it?

```
function Copy() {
  var theSelection = document.selection.createRange();
  alert(theSelection.text);           
}

 <div>
    <span class="Icon" onclick="Copy();"></span> <input type="button" value="Copy" onclick="Copy();" style="float:left;" />  
 </div>
 <div style="clear:both;">
    <textarea rows="2" cols="20" style="height:370px;width:800px;"></textarea> 
 </div>
```

---

**IE only!**

[Online Example](http://www.webdevout.net/test?0V&raw)

Update:

This is how I do it in firefox:

```
if (window.getSelection){ // Firefox, Opera, Safari

   var textbox = document.getElementById("box");
   textbox.focus();
   theSelection = document.activeElement.value.substring(document.activeElement.selectionStart, document.activeElement.selectionEnd);

alert(theSelection);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly it: by the time the click event fires, the selection has been lost. It will work if you use `onmousedown` instead of `onclick`.

**UPDATE**

Another alternative that works in IE only is to add the following attribute to the `<span>`. This prevents the span from affecting the selection by making it unselectable:

```
unselectable="on"
```

**UPDATE 2**

In other browsers, the way to get the selected text is to use the `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties:

```
function Copy() {
    var textbox = document.getElementById("box");
    textbox.focus();
    var selectedText = "";
    if (typeof textbox.selectionStart == "number") {
        selectedText = textbox.value.slice(textbox.selectionStart, textbox.selectionEnd);
    } else if (document.selection) {
        selectedText = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    alert(selectedText);
}
```

Comment: mousedown is not the behavior i desire ... I want it to work on mouse up like any other button

Comment: OK. Buttons just work differently, I think because they don't affect the selection. Anyway, updating my answer...

Comment: yes, this works. and finally please check my update and tell if I do it right for firefox... maybe there is a better way then using focus...